# How to extract value from the JSON if the body is string type in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-5.0

I am getting response as

{
"statusCode": 219,
"body": "{"message": "otp sent to user", "session": "f603ee03-4906-4451-b4e5-b19f0ccf84d0", "otp": "123456"}"
}

I want to get the Session number  from this response. Do we have any suggestions

I tried post processors however couldn't as the response is in string

Answer (score 0):

This is really strange response. It looks like valid json but isnt really. You can try with regular expression extractor with this expression to match the UUID:

```
[0-9a-f]{8}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{12}
```

[image]

Comment: Hello Alex, Thanks for the answer. I tried it but didn't worked so I used JS223 Post Processor and used Groovy script to get the response and  used substring functionality.

Answer (score 0):

If the response **really** looks **exactly** how you're posting it - you won't be able to use JSON Extractor because it's not a valid JSON

You can use either [Regular Expression Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor) and the regex like:

```
session"\s?:\s?"(.+?)"
```

[image]

If you want explanation:

- `\s?` - optional whitespace character
- `()` - grouping
- `.` - any character
- `+` - repetition
- `?` - don't be greedy, stop at first match

Or [Boundary Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Boundary_Extractor) configured like:

[image]

More information: [The Boundary Extractor vs. the Regular Expression Extractor in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-boundary-extractor)

Comment: Hello Dmitri, Thanks for the answer. I tried it but didn't worked so I used JS223 Post Processor and used Groovy script to get the response and used substring functionality.